# adb not working with variable in bash

Tags: android, linux, bash, adb

I'm trying to export all apks from my android phone (rooted).

I have dumped all the packages using `adb shell pm list` into a file.

```
com.google.android.ears
com.android.voicedialer
...
```

Now I want to download them, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
        echo "Name: $line"
        # get package path
        p=$(adb shell pm path $line);
        # remove package: prefix
        p=$(echo $p | grep -Po "(?<=package:).*" | xargs)
        echo "Path: $p"
        # download it
        adb pull $p
done;
```

I get stuff like this:

```
Name: com.google.android.ears
Path: /system/app/GoogleEars.apk
' does not exist/system/app/GoogleEars.apk
Name: com.android.voicedialer
Path: /system/priv-app/VoiceDialer.apk
' does not exist/system/priv-app/VoiceDialer.apk
Name: com.android.defcontainer
^C
```

When I do it manually in terminal, it works just fine.

Why it doesn't work here?

Comment: This line `p=$(echo $p | grep -Po "(?<=package:).*" | xargs)` looks most suspicious to me. What is the value of `$p` before that line? Also, quoting your variables is always a good idea.

Comment: Look at the outputs, after that line Path is as it should be.

Comment: If you say so but clearly there's something subtle going on - are you saying that if you just do `adb pull com.google.android.ears` then that works? By the way I think `p=$(awk -F: '/package/{print $2}'<<<"$p")` would be a simpler alternative.

Comment: Your problem is probably the carriage returns which adb unhelpfully sneaks into its responses for windows compatibility.  You don't typically see these on a unix terminal, but they wreak havoc with traditional line-by-line shell script processing unless stripped out in your script.

Comment: this has been discussed many times. do `adb shell pm list packages | tr -d '\r'` to get your list

Comment: also see if https://gist.github.com/ktnr74/33029fba8233f9a7879c would be of any help

Comment: thanks @ChrisStratton AND @AlexP, it indeed was the carriage returns. I wonder what genius thought adding `\r` is a good idea - it's a Linux build anyway. Putting `set -x` into the script revealed the havoc, and `tr -d '\r'` indeed nicely cleaned it up.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the `adb` commands end with a `\r`. You have to remove it from this line, too

```
p=$(adb shell pm path $line)
```

with something like

```
p=$(adb shell pm path $line | tr -d '\r')
```

I see another problem: many apks will be overwritten as `base.apk`

```
Name: com.google.android.youtube
Path: /data/app/com.google.android.youtube-1/base.apk
Name: net.mx17.overridedns
Path: /data/app/net.mx17.overridedns-2/base.apk
Name: com.android.email
Path: /system/app/Email/Email.apk
```

So I think I'd do it with something like

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  echo "Name: $line"
  # get package path
  p=$(adb shell pm path $line | sed 's/^package://;s/\r$//')
  echo "Path: $p"
  # get package name
  name=$(echo $p | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}')
  echo "Package name: $name"
  # download it
  adb pull $p ${name}.apk
done < <(adb shell pm list packages | sed 's/^package://;s/\r$//')
```